# Is there a common file that contains the localized text of each country?

Tags: localization, translation

Is there a common file that contains the localized text of each country?

The content is the words frequently used by the application, such as [submit] [cancel], and so on.

Just using this file we can create applications in various languages ​​without having to translate them ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Translation Memory (TM). TM is a database of the source strings and their corresponding translations into different languages that can speed up the translation of the same or similar strings in your projects.

The thing here is that the file you're looking for probably doesn't exist because such a file would be huge and a bit not usable.

Translation Memories - is one of the core concepts in modern CAT (Computer-Assisted Translation) Tools.

There are a bunch of offers on the CAT Tools market that provide the **Global Translation Memory** feature. Global TM is a huge database of billions of previously made translations in different projects for different language pairs.

For example, [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) is a popular Localization Management platform that has a Global TM with billions of previously translated texts and allows users to use this TM for translating their strings. Furthermore, the process could be totally automated.

Comment: Can we extract the words we want and their national translations from this huge database?

Comment: @normidar it's possible by enabling the Global TM option in the [project settings](https://support.crowdin.com/project-settings/#translation-memory) and then [Applying Translation Memory via Pre-translation](https://support.crowdin.com/translation-memory/#applying-translation-memory-via-pre-translation). Before that, you'll need to upload your localization files to the project